# What to do about ambiguous tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, ambiguous-tags

I just answered a question pertaining to the LOGO language (yes, the turtle pusher) and, as I sometimes do, went to examine other questions with the same tag.

Interestingly enough, they seem to be fairly equally divided into questions about the LOGO language and things like "How do I create a logo for my site?" type questions.

What's the best way to handle conflicts like this? Should they be split, and how?

There's no wiki for this tag (and I don't have the power to create one anyway) so it's not immediately obvious to me which is the best way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see the image related use as a proper tag on Stack Overflow.

Even where we are looking at a *programming* question (by no means guaranteed) there is nothing special about programming for logos as opposed to other image.

A quick scan through the question mostly confirms this with only a few exceptions:

- [Increase Apple Logo Brightness with Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1436193/2509) which is about accessing a hardware component on macs
- [Can I use the Windows logo in my software as an icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2722384/2509), [using browser logos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3352814/2509), and [What Google logo can i use on my site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3365978/2509) which are intellectual property questions
- [What company's FavIcon Logo is this? Popular CMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3327683/2509) clearly off-topic

**My suggestion:** reserve [logo](/questions/tagged/logo) for the language, close and delete the junk, and replace the image related uses with [image-generation](/questions/tagged/image-generation) or something else appropriate.

Comment: This.  As it pertains to programming, the word logo is reserved for a language.  There is no need to discuss business/trademark logos on stackoverflow specifically separate from other images.  Questions discussing business logos that aren't programming questions, and aren't image related probably don't belong on stackoverflow.

Comment: I acted on this one, and hopefully the powers that be won't boot my in the rear end for doing so :-) `Logo` has been reserved for the programming language. It says so in the tag wiki. Which I also created so the only support there is coming from myself but that's usually more than enough to convince me :-) I also retagged all the others with `graphical-logo`.

Answer (score 2):

I think they need to be split.  Possibly into something like: `logo-language` and `logo-image`.

I would not want to be searching for one and seeing results for the other mixed in.